# Consultas a BD desde laravel a prestashop

Tags: laravel, prestashop

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto de `laravel` desde el cual me conecto a dos BD.
Una de las BD a la que me conecto es la de `prestashop` y necesito realizar consultas sobre esta BD. Os comento a continuación (si me equivoco en algo, corregidme).

Hasta aquí todo bien, defino las conexiones en `database.php` para poder conectarme a la  las dos BD, creo los modelos para acceder a las tablas (ejemplo a continuación):

```
protected $connection = 'prestashop';

protected $table = 'product';
```

Con esto consigo sacar información de las tablas, incluso definiendo las relaciones en el modelo puedo acceder a información de otras tabla de manera sencilla.

El problema viene cuando por ejemplo quiero actualizar registros en la tabla "product". Realizo una consulta para obtener un registro, cambio el valor de uno de los campos y cuando realizo un "save" obtengo un error indicando que no encuentra la columna "id".

```
$product->save();
$product->update();
```

Entiendo que `laravel` sigue un estándar y cuando quiere actualizar un registro realiza una consulta con una clausula where para una columna llamada "id" y en este caso en prestashop, la clave primaria de la tabla donde quiero actualizar se llama  "id_product".

No sé si con los métodos que ofrece `laravel` esto se puede cambiar.
¿Hay alguna manera de indicar que dichas consultas las haga sobre la columna "id_product"??

He visto que se pueden hacer consultas de manera manual, pero si puedo evitar eso, mejor.

Gracias!

**Edito:**

Hasta el momento, obtenía el registro de la siguiente manera **(aquí si obtengo el registro y da el error cuando realiza el update)**:

```
$product = Product::where('reference', '=', $data['partnumber'])->first();
        $product->price = $data['price'];           
        $product->save();
```

También he probado de otra manera **(Aquí no obtiene registro, da el mismo error ya que busca por la columna "id")**:

```
$product = Product::find($data['id_product']);          
        $product->price = $data['price'];
        $product->save();
```

El problema está en que busca con la clausula where una columna llamada `id` y la columna que tiene que buscar con la clausula se llama `id_product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leyendo un poco sobre `laravel` y haciendo algunas pruebas he visto que se puede hacer lo siguiente.

Se debe de hacer con `update()` obteniendo el registro por la clave primaria de la tabla de prestashop (se le debe especificar los campos a actualizar como parámetros):

```
$product = Product::where('id_product', $data['id_product'])->update(['price' => $data['price']]);
```

**NOTA:** Como `laravel` sigue un standar, al actualizar registros, la consulta que realiza actualiza también la columna llamada `updated_at` y por lo tanto como se está actualizando la tabla `product` de `prestashop` dicha columna no existe.
Esto se puede solucionar indicando que ignore las columnas `timestamp` en el modelo de la tabla:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Esto es lo que dice la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions):

> **Primary Keys**
>
> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named `id`. You may define a protected `$primaryKey` property to override this convention.

Entonces en tu modelo tienes que agregar:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id_product';
```

Answer (score 1):

Es porque no estas siguiendo las bases de uso de los modelos de objetos de PrestaShop, para actualizar un objeto debes indicar el id del mismo en la instancia.

```php
$product = new Product($id_product);
$product->price = 111.11;
// Resto de objetos a modificar aqui (opcionales)
$product->save();
```

Para crear un nuevo objeto debes instanciar sin parámetros.

```php
$product = new Product();
$product->price = 111.11;
// Resto de objetos a modificar aqui (obligatorios)
$product->save();
```

Comment: El tema es que, si creo un nuevo objeto, cuando yo haga un "save" me va a crear un nuevo registro en la tabla de la BD y lo que yo necesito es actualizar un registro de la tabla.

Comment: Si revisas el código de la clase base `ObjectModel` te darás cuenta que `save()` crea uno nuevo o actualiza de forma automática, esto en dependencia de si el id que le estás enviando en la instancia existe o no.